# A non-existent service "form.csrf_provider" requested

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-3.3

I have made changes in security.yml file as

> csrf_provider to csrf_token_generator in security.yml

But when I accessing the csrf from controller like this

```
$csrfToken = $this->container->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate');
```

or

```
$csrfToken = $this->container->get('form.csrf_token_generator')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate');
```

But the issue remain same.

Please tell me how to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I Used This Method to get the code : $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('authenticate')->getValue();

Comment: Wow, it's working fine. Thanks!!!...
$this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('authent‌​icate'); I have tried with this but not able to get the exact value.
Thanks a lot

Comment: your welcome i will put it in answers section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can Used This Method to get the $csrfToken

```
$csrfToken = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('authenticate')->getValue();
```